# iTunes Connect Apps Localisation

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

I'm trying to localisation of application in Spanish but Then User Search application in Spain iTunes Show Description in English UK

How Can i Show Spanish localisation MetaData in Spain Not in English UK ?[image]

[image]

Comment: is that a screenshot from Mobile Safari or from the App Store app or?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Localize Application Description in Spanish on iTunes Store.In iTunes Store use can localize application description in various language. If you Add Application description in Spanish language then When user see app in Spanish store the app description show in Spanish language.
As you see language list in screen shot. You need to select Spanish for that and add description for that language. you can also define application screenshot as per language on that page.
[image]

Comment: Also check with https://itunes.apple.com/es  where es is country code for spain app store.

Comment: Hi Hiren already Add Spanish Language in Localization but in Share Image User in Spain and search our app but Show English Translation.

Comment: Hi Hiren i already Add Spanish Language in Localization. Inn Share pic User or Spain then Search Our App Show English Translation.

Comment: Hi Hiren I'm Add one more image in Question That iTunesConnect Localization Pic.

Comment: If user is in spain but he/she set is region or store is US then US store will be display to User instead of Spain if use is also in spain. Store is Deside based on User's login not based on current location of user. check User has set store Spain or not in account.